# orthotropic materials solution of boundary value problems

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, deformation-theory, physics

What are the methods or approaches for the analytical solutions of boundary value problems in the theory of elasticity for orthotropic materials?

Comment: The same methods as for other partial differential equations. 

Answer (score 1):

Analytical methods of solution are typically restricted to two-dimensional geometries, see for example
[Applications of symmetry methods in basic problems of orthotropic elasticity](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00036819908840761) (1999)

> We discuss basic problems of
>   orthotropic elasticity in a plane
>   domain whose boundary is a
>   piecewise-algebraic curve. First, by
>   means of bi-analytic functions, a
>   basic problem is reduced to a boundary
>   value problem for analytic functions.
>   Then, by use of the generalized
>   symmetry principle for algebraic
>   curves, a boundary value problem for
>   analytic functions is converted to a
>   problem on a Riemann surface; then the
>   solution to the original problem is
>   obtained in closed form for a domain
>   with algebraic boundaries having genus
>   $\rho\geq 0$.

Numerical methods in three dimensions are discussed in [A matrix decomposition method for orthotropic elasticity problems](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0610004) (1989).